# Как вывести ссылку на скачивания файла

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма

```
<form action="1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="raz"  />
<input type="text" value="введите код" name="code" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Создал БД,где хранятся картинки

$

```
rs=getimagesize($_FILES['raz']['tmp_name']);
if(!empty( $_FILES['raz']['name'] ) && $rs[0]>0){ 
echo 'images downloaded'."\n".'<br>';
 $image = file_get_contents( $_FILES['raz']['tmp_name'] );
  $image = mysql_escape_string( $image );
  $size=$_FILES['raz']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['raz']['type'];
  $name=$_FILES['raz']['name'];
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('new_bd');
$sql2="CREATE TABLE files (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
size INT NOT NULL, 
content MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);";
$sql="INSERT INTO `files`(name,type,size,content) VALUES(
'".$name."','".$type."','".$size."','".$image."')";
```

Теперь хочу обратную задачу решить:вводим число в форму и оно должно вывести ссылку на скачивание файла
Пытался сделать так

```
<form action="2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--<input type="file" name="raz"  />-->
<input type="text" value="введите код" name="code" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

2.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['code'])){
    $code=$_POST['code'];
    $conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db('new_bd');
         $query = "SELECT `content` FROM `files` WHERE `id`='".$code."'";
    // Выполняем запрос и получаем файл
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if ( mysql_num_rows( $res ) == 1 ) {
      $image = mysql_fetch_array($res);
      // Отсылаем браузеру заголовок
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
      // И  передаем сам файл
      echo "<a href='".$image['content']."'>opa</a>";
        }
        }
Ошибка именно в формировании ссылки
```

Comment: А почему MIME `header("Content-type: aplication/*");` ?

Comment: header("Content-type: image/jpg");
      // И  передаем сам файл
      echo $image['content'];
    }
Картинка выводится,осталось сделать ссылку на скачивания.
echo "<a href='".$image['content']."'>opa</a>";-ошибка.

Comment: > <a href='".$image['content']."'>opa</a>   

Это что за идиотизм?

Comment: ну получилось так...

Comment: @koza4ok, Вы ссылку на картинку так не сможете передать - потому что, во-первых, Вы получаете картинку Post'ом, а его в ссылке не передать, а во-вторых вы вместо ссылки в ссылку кидаете содержание картинки и !передаёте ссылку с этим содержанием как картинку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--<input type="file" name="raz"  />-->
<input type="text" value="введите код" name="code" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
<?php if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code'])){
    $code = intval($_POST['code']);
    echo "<img src=\"2.php?code=$code\" alt=\"Image\" />";
    echo "<a href=\"2.php?code=$code\" title=\"Image\" />";
}?>
```

2.php

```
if(isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code'])){
    $code=intval($_GET['code']);
    $conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db('new_bd');
         $query = "SELECT `content` FROM `files` WHERE `id`='".$code."'";
    // Выполняем запрос и получаем файл
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if ( mysql_num_rows( $res ) == 1 ) {
      $image = mysql_fetch_array($res);
      // Отсылаем браузеру заголовок
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
      // И  передаем сам файл
      echo $image['content'];
        }
      }
```